# Telnet Server ubuntu - password stream

Tags: python, telnet, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to create a Telnet Server using Python on Ubuntu 12.04. In order to be able to execute commands as a different user, I need to use the `su` command, which then prompts for the password. Now, I know that the prompt is sent to the STDERR stream, but I have no idea which stream I am supposed to send the password to. If I try to send it via STDIN, I get the error: `su: must be run from a terminal`. How do I proceed?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. The world has moved to SSH to stop passwords from being sniffed off the network.


That said, have you thought about running the telnet server as the user you require or run the telnet server as root and do os.setuid() before executing the command.

You could also use a normal SSH server and use sudo.

Comment: As long as i finish implementing Telnet, i can add network security layer to it. Problem is not running it as root or that user. Problem is logging into the system with the password given by the remote user.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo` instead of `su` with the `-S` (stdin) option which causes `sudo` to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device?

Comment: Hey thanks it worked !! I can use 'sudo -S su username < passwordfile' and use 'commands.getstatusoutput()' to check if i logged in successfully now instead of complicated subprocess handles.

Comment: `must be run from a terminal` means you can't drive it from another program via a pipe (unless you put the program into a pseudo-termimal).  Glad `sudo` is working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use system's `su` program, you will need to create a terminal pair, see `man 7 pty`, in python that's `pty.openpty` call that returns you a pair of file descriptors, one for you and one for su. Then you have to fork, in the child process change stdin/out/err to slave fd and exec su. In the parent process you send data to and receive data from master fd. Linux kernel connects those together.

Alternatively you could perhaps emulate `su` instead?

Comment: i thought of a simpler solution using `'mkpasswd -m sha-512 --salt=%s -s < pass'%salt` to generate the hashes for entered password and checking it from /etc/shadow